# Child widget decoration color based on gradient color points- flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am using gradient color as my Scaffold background. And I am placing different widgets under Scaffold with borders. I am trying to place some texts in border with the same background color. How it possible?

```
 Align( 
    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,  
    child: Transform.translate( 
       offset: Offset(10, -5),         
         child: Container(color: widget.color, child: Text(label),)),),
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you give us any code to look at? You would normally just use `BoxDecoration`.

Comment: Actually, I am using border decorations for drop down button.. To add material outline hint I have to specify a color.. I am using gradient color as background. And I have different widgets that have the same feature.

Comment: Can you please reproduce an example on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev)?